# Fixed Effects Regression with unbalanced panel data set

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel data set that captures forum member's online behaviour for a period of five years at monthly intervals (t = 63). The total number of forum members in the data set is around 12,000. Since forum members are able to join and leave the forum as they please, the data set is unbalanced, with many members active for a considerably shorter period than the full 63 months.

I am running a fixed effects regression in python using the PanelOLS package from linearmodels. I am told repeatedly that this method is able to deal with unbalanced panel data, though I am unsure what this means (or how this is achieved), and since the research is for my masters thesis I feel like I should explain the procedure that it adopts to deal with the unbalancedness.

Could anyone shine some light on how it deal with this? Or if not, would it be a better idea to balance the dataset by populating all inactive months for every forum member with zeroes?

Comment: I do not have a solution but I am currently having a similar data for my research project as well. I would like to know if you were able to come up with any solution for the unbalanced monthly data. Thanks in Advance.